# What is the purpose of the inductor for this Vcc bus?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I sometimes see an inductor is used along with decoupling capacitors as in the example below:

[image]

Above it seems the node VCC is filtered to obtain the VCC_+5V node.

I can understand that the decupling capacitor provides very low impedance relative to the ground hence remove the noise from the Vcc bus, but if the inductor L1 above is used for the same purpose (to attenuate the noise) what/how can it perform that a capacitor cannot?

Comment: You might also see a ferrite bead in a similar position, which function slightly differently but may be drawn with the same symbol. They have the same overall purpose, just go about it a slightly different way that's more effective for certain things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Capacitors used to filter supply lines rely on stray resistance and stray inductance in the supply line as well as the source impedance itself to drop the unwanted voltage ripple and noise. This can be quite challenging for the capacitor current can become quite large. Strategically placing extra resistance and inductance where very low noise is desired is quite common.

**Update:**

I added an update to provide a visual on how filtering works on a power line. This called a circuit because electrons flow in a circle.

Also I want to show that "capacitors do not route noise to ground". Capacitors respond to changing voltage by changing the amount of current flowing through them. If there is no series component to drop the voltage the desired voltage filtering will not happen. The loop current through the power supply will increase, likely making things worse through magnetic coupling to adjacent circuits.
The first simulation below shows a noise source (V1) in series with VCC. The values are exaggerated for demonstration. R1 represents the internal resistances of the sources. It is quite small compared to the load R2.

The red trace clearly shows the unwanted noise represented by a 100kHz sine wave. The blue line is the desired value supplied by VCC. The lower trace shows the current through R1 which is the current supplied by the power supply.

Watch what happens when a filter capacitor is placed across the load.

[image]

A \$100\mu\text{F}\$ is placed across the load. The noise voltage across R2 is reduced to about 17mV peak. But at what cost. The noise current in the circuit has increased to a whopping 1A peak.

[image]

The third image is the same as the second with a measurement showing that the noise voltage appears across R1 as the blue-green line.

The capacitor did not route the noise to ground. The noise voltage is essentially transferred to the internal resistance of the source (R1). The noise still exists but nowhere near the load (R2). The big downside is the huge current that is required to achieve the noise reduction.

[image]

Adding a small \$10\mu\text{H}\$ inductor in series with the source reduces the noise across R2 even further down to a few millivolts.

[image]

But now the noise current is just \$170 \text{mA}\$ peak. So where did the noise voltage go? Some is still across the R1. The rest is across the inductor. Increasing the capacitance across the load will also reduce the noise but the loop current will go up.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you saying the job of the inductor is to mitigate the noise amplitude so that capacitor can handle it without exceeding its max limits?

Comment: No. Filtering is based in a voltage divider. The inductor presents a high resistance to high frequency signals. It’s not about exceeding the capacitor’s limits. It is using two elements to do a better job of filtering than just one.

Comment: But a large  cap already can route the noise to ground. I dont get what can happen without the inductor. Remove L1 and increase C10 isnt that the same thing?

Comment: Please refer to my update.

Comment: @ty_1917 think of it like a voltage divider.

Comment: I think I got it. The inductor act as R in the RC circuit. But at very high freq. inductor will block AC but pass DC. So it will not effect DC. If big R was used instead that would drop voltage. So at low freq RC is good with small R. And the reason we dont use huge cap is because it would require huge current. So the best is to balance all these.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 12):

- Capacitors by nature, oppose changes in voltage.  If a cap is charged to 5V, then instantly supplied a 6V pulse, a very large current must flow before it will reach 6V.  So in that sense, sudden changes in voltage are reduced (by absorbing and emitting current.)  This has the net effect of filtering "pulse" voltage noise.
- Inductors by nature, oppose changes in current.  If an inductor is has 50mA flowing through it, then is instantly supplied 60mA pulse, the voltage will do "whatever it has to" to maintain that 50mA.  So in that sense, sudden changes in current are reduced (by absorbing and emitting voltage.)  This has the net effect of filtering "pulse" current noise.

Together, these can make a very effective filter due to their ability to "filter" both aspects (voltage noise, current noise) of power.  However, putting both together has (in the case of power filtering) the unwanted side-effect of resonance.  A capacitor and inductor together is sometimes called a [resonant tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit) circuit.  These tend to resonate at a certain frequency based on their values. R3 in the diagram helps to reduce this resonance.

Comment: What can cause the sudden change in current? Like what can create 60mA pulse current directly without byproduct of voltage?

Comment: @ty_1917 One way is through capacitive coupling, for example. Say you circuit is in the vicinity of some other circuit where there is considerable dv/dt (e.g. switching regulator). There may be a parasitic capacitive path (coupling) such that noise currents can flow. Recall that current in a capacitor is ic=C*dv/dt. The dv/dt produced in that other circuit can excite the coupling capacitance. You can think of a similar situation with inductive coupling where di/dt can induce voltage somewhere else.

Comment: Because voltage and current exist together. Im super confused even though I know the formulas. A large cap already can route the noise to ground. I dont get what can happen without the inductor. Remove L1 and increase C10 isnt that the same thing? If dv/dt (the switching regulator) creates current pulse wouldn't the decoupling capacitor route it to ground easily? Switching means high freq and the cap should be low impedance to that(pulse) as well.

Comment: @ty_1917 you have to think in simple resistor circuitry. The inductor and capacitor make a voltage divider, like with normal resistors. And they have another configuration for different frequencies at the same time. Now also draw this for the case there is no inductor.

Answer (score 7):

Inductors and capacitors work differently, but can be combined to create stronger noise attenuation and isolation than using each type alone.

In this case the inductor can block noise coming from the input as well as noise generated in the device. In contrast, the capacitors will be mostly for shunting local noise to keep it within the device as the inductor is already blocking the noise.

Second time today, I recommend this Murata doc: https://www.murata.com/-/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/emc/emifil/c39e.ashx

Answer (score 0):

The inductor in a circuit effectively prevents capacitance on either side of it from being used to smooth out variations in current draw on the other.  While it might seem that one would want to have the combined capacitance on both sides of the inductor to be available to smooth out fluctuations, there are a couple of problems:

1. When capacitance is used to smooth out fluctuations in draw, the voltage on the capacitors will fluctuate as a consequence.  It's much easier to ensure that capacitors are adequate to control fluctuations in a board's supply voltage caused by its own fluctuating current draw.  It's much harder to ensure that voltage fluctuations will be acceptable if the caps are also controlling the fluctuations on outside boards.
2. High speed fluctuations in voltage and current can radiate RF energy.  If all fluctuations caused by circuitry on a board are confined to the board, the designer of the board can determine what kinds of shielding or other measures would be needed to keep emitted RF to acceptable levels.  If fluctuations on one board may be conveyed to other boards designed by someone else, it may be much harder to know how much energy that other board might radiate as a consequence.

Note that in many cases, adding an inductor to a board's power supply input may cause its supply rail to be noisier than it would otherwise be, but a certain amount of noise confined to a single board may be less problematic than a larger amount of noise that's more widely distributed.